# Route a Virtual IP without NAT to a non-virtual IP

Tags: ubuntu, routing, icmp

How can I route data with a Linux server (Ubuntu) from a VIP to another IP address. I'm currently using keepalived, but it uses a NAT and I don't want that. However, it should be checked via icmp which IP is routed online and to the currently available IP. The way back would be logically asymmetrical

Does anyone have an idea or can help me?

Thanks very much..

Comment: hi! what is a VIP?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. This is a bit unclear. Can you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/740908/edit) the question and expand this so what exactly you're after is clear, and what exactly is your current setup? Why you want to avoid NAT? When asking for assistance, the devil's in the details - the more you provide the better answers you get. @MarcusMüller - VIP = Virtual IP address; an IP that's not bound to any physical interface. That allows for example moving services from one host to another with ease etc.

Comment: ah I know that under the term "floating IP address".

Comment: @MarcusMüller A very descriptive term, I'd say :-D I wasn't even aware of the concept until today :-)

Comment: I'm not really clear what the question is here. `keepalived` itself doesn't use NAT; it just manages IP assignment on a group of machines.

Comment: @larsks in addition to VRRP, keepalived handles IPVS for load balancing. One of the modes of IPVS is using NAT (in keepalived.conf `lb_kind NAT` or `lvs_method NAT` depending on the version). Of course OP has to give way more information to be helped (like the complete keepalived setup and the network layout).